# Class has no member "Class"

Tags: c++, constructor

I am trying to create a class called `Drone`, and have two files, `Drone.h` and `Drone.cpp`.

**Drone.h**

```
class Drone {
protected:
    void foo();
};
```

**Drone.cpp**

```
#include "Drone.h"

Drone::Drone()  // <---ERROR
{
}

void Drone::foo()
{
}
```

I get the error:

> "Class 'Drone' has no member Drone."

in the tooltip as I hover over Drone. In the compiler, it gives the error:

> error C2600: 'Drone::Drone' : cannot define a compiler-generated special member function (must be declared in the class first)

Why is this? All I am trying to do is make a constructor for Drone.

Comment: ...you haven't declared the constructor inside `Drone`.

Comment: Man thats a nice drone, what are you going to name it and how much will it cost?

Comment: Wow, I'm so sorry. I was even comparing it to old .cpp files to try and see the difference and I somehow kept blowing right past it. I can't accept an answer yet, but this is solved.

Comment: I have updated your question to be more generic. Could you please add the exact error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have not explicitly declared a default constructor in your header file:

```
class Drone {
protected:
    void foo();
public:
    Drone(); // <----
};
```

Every member function, including constructors and operators, must be declared before a definition can be specified.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your constructor in the header as well:

```
class Drone {
public:
    Drone();
protected:
    void foo();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

All memebers, including constructors, need to be declared in the class definition. You can't add members in other places.

Answer (score 0):

First function called after creating object is `constructor` which having same name.

```
"Class 'Drone' has no member Drone."
        ^^^^^==>class        ^^^^^===>constructor
```

declare it in header file:

```
class Drone {
public:
    Drone(); //decleared
protected:
    void foo();
};
```