# C++ Error C2600: Cannot define a compiler-generated special member function (must be declared in the class first)

Tags: c++, class, constructor, copy-constructor

I'm receiving C2600 error (in title) when compiling a simple program making use of custom copy constructors.

My .h file is

```
#pragma once

namespace uiuc {
    class Cube {
    public:
        Cube();
        double getVolume();
        double getSurfaceArea();
        void setLength(double length);

    private:
        double length_;
    };
}
```

My Cube.cpp file is

```
#include "Cube.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace uiuc {
    Cube::Cube() {
        length_ = 1;
        std::cout << "Default consturctor invoked" << std::endl;
    }
    Cube::Cube(const Cube& obj) {
        length_ = obj.length_;
        std::cout << "Copy consturctor invoked" << std::endl;
    }

    double Cube::getVolume() {
        return length_ * length_* length_;
    }
    double Cube::getSurfaceArea() {
        return 6 * length_* length_;
    }
    void Cube::setLength(double length) {
        length_ = length;
    }
}
```

And my main.cpp file is

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Cube.h"

int main() {

    uiuc::Cube c;
    uiuc::Cube mycube = c;

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why this error is being thrown. Any suggestions?

Edit:
Thanks so much for the quick responses. I'm brand-new to C++, so sorry if this seemed trivial.
The fix, as mentioned by others was to add `Cube(const Cube& obj);` to the header file.

Comment: Add this declaration into your class definition `Cube(const Cube& obj);`

Comment: The compiler error is telling you *exactly* what's wrong, and how you can fix it.

Comment: Compilers don't throw errors, sorry but it's fast becoming a pet peeve of mine.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30453975/class-has-no-member-class) and [several others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=C2600+is%3Aq) are almost identical, except that they try to define the default constructor without declaring it in the class defntion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't declare the constructor in your .h file.

It should look like this:

```
#pragma once

namespace uiuc {
    class Cube {
    public:
        Cube();
        Cube(const Cube& obj); // This was missing.
        double getVolume();
        double getSurfaceArea();
        void setLength(double length);

    private:
        double length_;
    };
}
```

Then after that should you be able to define it outside the class definition.

Answer (score 1):

The function:

```
Cube::Cube(const Cube& obj) {
    length_ = obj.length_;
    std::cout << "Copy consturctor invoked" << std::endl;
}
```

is declared in the cpp file as a member function of `Cube`, but it is missing in your class definition.

It should be in here:

```
class Cube {
public:
    Cube(const Cube& obj)    
    // ...
};
```